# how to add Search functionality in android recyclerView using Volley library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-volley, searchview

I am making android application in which I am doing search within RecyclerView Items. request is going to server successfully. Basically I am making search with keyword. The problem is how i can send search keyword to server and load data according to that keyword.
here is my search activty:

Comment: Have you tried using Retrofit instead? It's recommended  in the official "Guide to App Architecture" by Google. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#fetching_data

Comment: no I am doing whole code using volley. that is why i am using volley

Comment: when you're doing the search you have already populated your recyclerview with the list you're gonna use? Or you need to do the request to server using the searchview to retrieve a list?

Comment: yesh. I am sending request to server with specific keyword. that keyword will retrieve data from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call getData() method in onTextChanged() and get string from search bar as

> searchItem = s.toString();

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
        count) {
        Log.d("onTextChanged", getClass().getSimpleName() + " text 
        changed " + searchBar.getText());
        searchItem = s.toString();
        Log.d("Text",searchItem);
        getData();
    }
```

Comment: yes. this is working but also showing irrelevant item

Comment: it will take time to update UI because if you want to search text then first api call to t then te then tex and last text so show loader then you will get related list last time

Comment: if you solved by this answer then rate up to this question @ansarabbas

Answer (score 0):

Use TextWatcher with TimerTask to avoid unwanted api triggers

call `startTask()` in your `onTextChanged()`

```
    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;

    private void startTask() {
            cancelTimers();
            timer = new Timer();
            timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    initSearch();
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 500);
        }

private void initSearch() {
    if (searchView != null && searchView.getQuery() != null) {
        String query = editText.getText().toString();
        setupAdapter(query);
    } else {
        setupAdapter(null);
    }
}



 private void setupAdapter(String query) {
        if (query != null) {
            // start Api call
        } else {
            //clearResults();
        }
    }



 private void cancelTimers() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }
        if (timerTask != null) {
            timerTask.cancel();
        }
    }
```